# $4^x + 5^x = 6^x$

Tags: contest-math

In a recent MathCounts Contest, the following question was asked

> If $x$ satisfies $4^x + 5^x= 6^x$ then find the greatest integer not greater than $x$

I tried to take logarithms of both sides, but then couldn't figure what to do with the $\log (4^x +5^x)$ part. Next, I tried to do some algebraic maneuvers to match the bases but failed in doing so.

How do I solve this problem and generally speaking, how do you tackle equations when the variable is in the exponent part?

(The time limit for solving the problem was 1 min and one guy solved it in under 10 seconds, which made me really curious, did he know the question from beforehand, or is there some kind of strategy?)

Comment: Just try small integer values for $x$.  That tells you the answer very quickly.  Remember, you are not asked to solve for $x$, just to get integer bounds on it.

Comment: $4^2+5^2>6^2$ and $4^3+5^3<6^3.$ Proving there is only one such $x$ is another problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**:
After dividing both side by $5^x$, we have $$\big(\frac45\big)^x+1=\big(\frac65\big)^x$$

Now, the left side is decreasing(power of a proper fraction) and right side is increasing(as, $6/5$ is greater than $1$) for $x>1$. So, maximum one root possible.

Comment: at $x=2$ left hand side is greater than right hand side. at $x=3$ left hand side is less than right hand side. So the answer is 2?

Comment: As the above argument shows only one root possible, so yeah, from the inequality, we have $2$ as answer.

Comment: thanks for helping out.